# jQuery sortable with containment parent and different item heights

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

*Please read this question together with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Q9b/12/).*

I have a jQuery Sortable list where I want to contain the items within the parent container while dragging - no problem - I use the `containment:'parent'` option.

**However, when the height of the second item is greater than the height of the first item, I am unable to drag the second item to the first position.**

I have tried unsuccessfully to use the additional option `tolerance:'pointer'` (my preference) nor does it work with the default `tolerance:'intersect'`.

I understand from the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-tolerance) that this is the expected behaviour for `tolerance` and works absolutely fine when the items have equal height.

**Is there a workaround for my scenario where the second item has greater height than the first item?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the option `cursorAt: { top:1 }` resolves the issue. Link to the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-cursorAt).

Unfortunately, I have subsequently discovered there is the same problem when trying to drag a tall item to the bottom of the list.

In the end my solution was to hack the `_intersectsWithPointer` function within `jquery.ui.sortable.js`.

I have replaced:

`var c = this.options.axis === "x" || a.ui.isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.top + this.offset.click.top, b.top, b.height),`

with:

`var c = this.options.axis === "x" || a.ui.isOverAxis(this.positionAbs.top + (this._getDragVerticalDirection() == "up" ? 0 : this.helperProportions.height), b.top, b.height),`

Now dragging any item of any height up- or downwards works absolutely fine.