# JQuery sortable (items with various heights) moving to first or last position is troublesome

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

**Problem**

I am having problems with my sortable list with several items of various height. The problem occurs when I'm trying to move a larger item to the first or last position (which both have smaller objects). If I succeed currently depends very much on where on the larger item I click and start dragging.

If I want to move the item to the smaller bottom position I must click close to the bottom of the item for it to work, and if I want to drag it to the top position I must click closely to the top. But I want to be able to drag the item by clicking anywhere.

**Some additional information**

The items cannot be dragged outside the parent and the parent is only as large as it has to be and a scroll appears if it's larger than it's container. So it seems that I cannot drag the larger item past the first(smaller) item if I don't drag it in the top part of the item.

I've been trying to fix this by using cursorAt and using top:0 and another test using bottom:0 But it doesn't seem to make any difference (so I might have misunderstood how to use it). I am currently using tolerance: pointer.

I can bypass the problem of not being able to drag the larger item to the last position by temporary during the sorting increasing the height with the height of the dragged item. But it doesn't always work and its not a very good solution. And the problem of not being able to drag it to the top still appears?

I cannot change the JQuery code as in [jquery-sortable-with-containment-parent-and-different-item-heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520532/jquery-sortable-with-containment-parent-and-different-item-heights)

**Question:**
*How can I drag a larger item to the top or bottom position while allowing the user to click anywhere on the item?*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your problem, but I thought I'd share the results of some experimenting I did today. I needed to make a sortable photo gallery with inline-block pictures of varying widths, and found that moving wider photos would be really hard work because the placeholder was smaller than the item I was moving. I ended up using this:

```
    container.sortable({
        placeholder: "photo placeholder",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.width());
        }
    });
```

The custom placeholder classes are there to ensure the placeholder isn't hidden by default, and the `start` event ensures that the placeholder is the same width as the item you're about to move. This worked very well for me, and in your case, substituting height for width might work.

I also tried using `containment` as you have done, and found that it sometimes makes things much harder depending on the items in the row. Like you have explained, including `tolerance: "pointer"` helps to alleviate the issues, but if possible, removing `containment` generally makes the UI more forgiving.